# WHERE clause through two tables

Tags: postgresql, join, time-series-database

I'm currently monitoring log events through an `log_events` table which references `web_pages`. Each web page belongs to a domain and has a classifcation. I've used an `inner join` so far for the query, however it seems incredibly slow over a dataset of 12 million log_events, 7 million web pages and 4 domains. Is there a better way of writing the query below or would there be a better data structure for this type of query?

Notes:

- The `$__timeFilter`, `$classifications` and `$domains` are variables from Grafana for visualising the results.
- Using Postgres 11 with TimescaleDB extension.

```
SELECT
  d.name
  e.status_code,
  count(e.status_code) as "status_count",
  cl.name,
  wp.path

from
    log_events e

inner join web_pages wp
    on e.web_page_id = wp.id
inner join classifications cl
    on wp.classification_id = cl.id
inner join domains d
    on wp.domain_id = d.id

where  $__timeFilter(e.visited_at) and (e.status_code >= 300) and cl.name in ($classifications) and d.name in ($domains)
group by d.name, e.status_code, cl.name, wp.path
order by status_count, cl.name
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Have you tried using [`EXPLAIN ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-explain.html) together with your `SELECT...`  statement? You might be missing an index or two. Post the results of the `EXPLAIN` to your original question. Just hit [edit] and add the nitty-gritty details.

Comment: Is your Grafana up to date?  Asking because https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/11578